# What is the best option for running a Jabber/XMPP on Windows 2003?

Tags: xmpp, instant-messaging

I'm looking to run a Jabber server on a Windows 2003 server(web farm) and like some practical advice from anyone who has run a live environment with ~500 concurrent users.

Criteria for comment:

- Performance
- Capacity (ie ~number of concurrent users)
- Stability

Comment: We are in the process or preparing a new installer for Windows if we have enough requests. We will announce it when ready on http://www.ejabberd.im

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're going to need to be a bit more explicit - you looking for server configurations, or software e.g. Jabber Server?

If you're thinking Jabber server, [EJabberD](http://www.ejabberd.im/) is probably the most stable, flexible, capable of being clustered etc.

Really useful comparison of Open Source servers here...

http://www.saint-andre.com/jabber/jsc/

Answer (score 5):

OpenFire is a good gpl java implementation of a jabber server.
It has plenty of option plugins you can use and it can intergrate quite well with Active Directory [OpenFire](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/index.jsp)